# How to fix the deserialization error when merging 2 kstreams topics using leftJoin?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I am new to Kafka. I am working on a personal project where I want to write to 2 different Avro topics and merge them using leftJoin. Once I merge them, I want to produce the same messages to a KSQL DB as well. (I haven't implemented that part yet).

I am using Kafka Template to produce to the 2 Avro topics and convert them into kstreams to merge them. I am also using KafkaListener to print any messages in them and that work is working. Here's where I am having issues at: 2 of them actually. In either cases, it doesn't produce any messages in the merged topic.

1. If I removed the `consumed.with()`from the kstream, then it throws a default key Serde error.
2. But if I keep it, then it throws a deserialization error.

I have even provided the default serialization and deserialization in both my `application.properties` and in the `streamConfig` inside `main()` but it's still not working.

Can somebody please help me with how to merge the 2 Avro topics? Is it error occurring because I am using the Avro schema? Should I use JSON instead? I wanna use a schema because my value part of the message will have multiple values in it.

For eg: `{Key : Value}` = `{company : {inventory_id, company, color, inventory}}` = `{Toyota : {0, RAV4, 50,000}}`

Here's a [link](https://gist.github.com/Arjun13/b76f53c9c2b4e88225ef71a18eb08e2f) to all the file: `application.properties`, `DefaultKeySerdeError.txt`, `DeserializationError.txt`, `FilterStreams.java`, `Inventory.avsc`, `Pricing.avsc`, and `MergedAvro.avsc` . Let me know if yall want me to put them below. Thank you very much for your help in advance!

https://gist.github.com/Arjun13/b76f53c9c2b4e88225ef71a18eb08e2f

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the [DeserializationError.txt](https://gist.github.com/Arjun13/b76f53c9c2b4e88225ef71a18eb08e2f#file-deserializationerror-txt-L18) file, it looks like the problem is you haven't provided the credentials for schema registry. Even though you have provided them in the [application.properties](https://gist.github.com/Arjun13/b76f53c9c2b4e88225ef71a18eb08e2f#file-application-properties-L11) file, they're not getting into the [serdes configuration](https://gist.github.com/Arjun13/b76f53c9c2b4e88225ef71a18eb08e2f#file-filterstreams-java-L155), so if you add the `basic.auth.user.info` configs to the `serdeConfig` map you should be all set.